# Class referenced in the manifest, was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: java, android-studio

Buenas tardes comunidad de Stack Overflow, tengo un error en el archivo "AndroidManifest.xml"
el cual dice:

> Class referenced in the manifest, `com.example.design.BienesMuebles`, was not found in the project or the libraries

Y la verdad no estoy seguro que pueda significar el error, ya que tengo la clase: BienesMuebles creada. Adjunto codigo del AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.design">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.NoActionBar">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainQR"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".editarUsuarios"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".registrosUsuarios"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BienesMuebles"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Registrar_Usuarios"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Usuarios"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Comprueba que el `Activity` tenga el mismo nombre `BienesMuebles`, que está en la ruta `com.example.design`, y que al abrirlo el nombre coincida `public class BienesMuebles`, parece ser un error de nomenclatura.

Comment: Ya comprobé que tenga el mismo nombre la clase, y también coincide la public class, y me sigue marcando el error.

Comment: Estoy teniendo el mismo problema que tu. Al parecer se origino al usar el Refactor del Android Studio para cambiar el nombre de una clase. Esto parece que ha hecho que se dañe alguna cosa internamente y me surge el problema que nos indicas.
Aunque parezca una tonteria, lo estoy solucionando manualmente buscando la clase que falla, añado un espacio y lo borro. Automaticamente la clase me la da como valida y se quita el problema.
En los fallos de la clase me indicaba que un metodo que se usa, no se usaba, posiblemente debido a que no se generaron bien las clases.
Espero que te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Debes asegurar tres cosas.

Primero revisa que la clase `BienesMuebles` extienda de `Activity`

Segundo, revisa que la clase `BienesMuebles` se encuentra dentro de la estructura de directorios

```
src/main/java/com/example/design
```

Tercero si lo anterior es correcto asegura que la clase  `BienesMuebles` tiene definido al inicio el paquete como:

```
package com.example.design
```

Comment: Comprobé que los tres puntos que resaltas fuesen correctos, y los son. No se que más se pueda hacer.

Comment: El problema indica que no existe la clase, tu clase BienesMuebles esta en el mismo directorio que MainActivity ?

Comment: Si, esta en el mismo directorio que el MainActivity. Me anexar una imagen para que lo compruebes.

Answer (score 0):

tenía justo el mismo problema. Se resolvió añadiendo al manifest la ruta específica donde se encuentra la actividad. En mi caso, cuando solo tenía al mainActivity(dentro de una carpeta llamada "ui") no generaba problemas,pero al añadir otra actividad en la misma carpeta se generó el error que mencionas.

Yo tenía antes: android:name=".StudyingActivity"
Se resolvió con: android:name=".ui.StudyingActivity"

Espero te sirva